# twice [as hard] as others; twice [as hard as others]

Tags: as, qualifiers

> He works **twice** as hard as others. ([naver.com](http://endic.naver.com/search.nhn?sLn=kr&isOnlyViewEE=N&query=twice%20as))
>   There are **twice** as many bikes as there are cars in the country. ([daum.net](http://dic.daum.net/search.do?q=twice%20as&dic=eng))

The quantifier, *twice*, is somewhat ambiguous to me. Does it modify [as hard] or [as hard as others]? In the second example, does it apply together?

Comment: I think it might help to relate this pattern to "twice that much" or "twice that many". For example, "However much they think that necklace is worth. This one is worth twice that much." In other words, "This necklace is worth twice as much as that one."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Twice* is two times in some sense. In

> He works **twice** as hard as others.

literally it modifies *as hard* (two times as hard). Though it could be used a relative judgment too (a lot harder).

> There are **twice** as many bikes as there are cars in the country.

This is literal, two times as many bikes as cars (ex. 10,000 bikes and 5,000 cars). *Twice* only applies to bikes.

Comment: Do you mean: There are [two times, such quantity of bikes,] comparing to the quantity of cars in the country?

Comment: 10,000 of anything is twice as many as 5,000. When referring to a known quantity n, "twice" literally means 2 * n.

"He works twice as hard as others" is hyperbole; an approximation. We are to infer that he works much harder than others, perhaps even "twice as hard."